# What is the source of /path/(null) requests?

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-8

We are beginning to see requests in our Apache Logs in the form

> /abc/(null)

These requests all have MSIE 8.0 and Trident 4.0 in the User-Agent field. The requests began to appear when we hadn't deployed any changed code for several weeks.

What is the source of these requests? Is this a bug in MSIE 8?

What is a systematic way to determine if this is a browser bug, javascript library bug or an issue with our code?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely either a buggy browser, buggy plugin, or a bot. There are a *lot* of bots out there crawling websites (badly) and pretending to be browsers.

I wouldn't worry about it unless it's actually causing a problem.

Here's a discussion of the (null) requests and how to block them: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3837651.htm

Comment: @eli What is a systematic way to determine if this is a browser bug, javascript library bug or an issue with our code? I'm drawing a blank thinking of how to debug this one.